# What does `&:` mean in this Ruby snippet?

Tags: ruby

This is from a solution I saw at a competitive programming site:

```
    gets.split.map &:to_i
```

The `&:to_i` phrase seems to be equivalent to `{|s| s.to_i}`, but I can't find anything about that syntax at ruby-doc.org, or a match for "&:" [ruby] here.  (I don't know what to call it for an English language search, either.)

If it matters, that site is using Ruby 3.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an example of `Symbol#to_proc` - see https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-ruby-idiom-map-with-symbol/ for a more detailed explanation, or [the ruby API documentation](https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/s?q=to_proc)

Comment: Thank you!  The API doc link is what I tried to find, but I still don't see how I'd have found it on my own if I didn't already know the answer to my question.